# Rendering 3D Model from OBJ File and MLT File Exported by Blender using three.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, 3d, three.js, blender

### Background

I want to render a 3D model in the `.obj` and `.mtl` file exported from Blender with **[this example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html)**. I just changed its original `.obj` and `.mtl` file to my own `.obj` and `.mtl` file but it does not work. The code is like the following.

```
THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath( '/' );
mtlLoader.load( 'demohead.mtl', function( materials ) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( '/' );
    objLoader.load( 'demohead.obj', function ( object ) {

        object.position.y = - 95;
        scene.add( object );

    }, onProgress, onError );

});
```

And I got the following 3D object. Only the basic meshes are rendered. The face is gone.

[image]

And an increasing number of the following error from the Google Chrome console: [image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'needsUpdate' of undefined
```

This error points to the render function call inside the animation loop. So the error keep appearing.

```
 renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

What I need to know for rendering a `.obj` file and `.mtl` file of a 3D model exported from Blender?

---

### Update

When I render the original cube or the monkey face in Blender. There are no any problem.

Comment: what line of what js module/script this error points at?

Comment: @prisoner849 - It points to the line: `renderer.render( scene, camera );`.